# How to turn off circular outlines around selection?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

[image: which blender interface button]

Something triggered these three circular outlines to appear around every object in the viewport?  I don't know what I did to trigger this, how do I undo it?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is shown here. Which mode is active? What kind of object do we see here? Which tool is active? This is the orthographical view? Can you add a description or provide a full screenshot next time, please?

Comment: Looks like a force field to me. Check the physics settings.